# why I receive mssage sent by my self, but cannot receive msg from otherst. XMPPFramework iOS

Tags: ios, xmppframework

I am studing the XMPPFramework of iOS. when I login user1 end send presence , user1 licent receive the precese. and when I sent mssage  to JID:user2 , user1 client was triger the  didRecieve func and message is from user2 to user1. Why the from and to are reversed?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you had send presence properly and code NSLog of [xmppStream isAuthenticated] and make sure it had value "1" then it will work.